# Laravel getting error after running the application few hours

Tags: laravel

**Update- The issue is fixed**

> After increasing the memory limit from index.php, the issue is fixed.

Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Container\Container::setInstance() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Container\Container or null, instance of Illuminate\Foundation\Application given and it works again after restart php7.3-fpm

Comment: Yes the Container instance accept only a container to initialize it with, but what is application instance that you made? What does it contain?

Comment: That's not a problem but why it's getting error after running few hours the application. If there any issue it should get at the start of the application.

Comment: Have you setup a worker maybe an event is scheduled??